# Альтернатива генераторов списков из python в java

Tags: java, python-3.x, генераторы

Есть ли в Java аналоги конструкциям - генераторам как в Python, позволяющие быстро создавать/заполнять массив?
Например, `mass = [x for x in range(10)]`
Можно ли похожий код написать в java?

Answer (score 3):

Наиболее близкое - стримы. В частности приведённый вами пример можно реализовать так

```
int[] mass = IntStream.range(0, 10).toArray();
```